# Trying to connect to ASPX site using CURL

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am trying to log into this url:

https://epayment.bank-maskan.ir/Banking/InstallmentShetab.aspx

this page has 4 inputs and some hidden inputs like __viewstate.

and this is my code:

```
<?php

$urlLogin = "https://epayment.bank-maskan.ir/Banking/InstallmentShetab.aspx";
$urlSecuredPage = "https://epayment.bank-maskan.ir/Banking/InstallmentShetab.aspx";
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

// POST names and values to support login
$namefield1='ctl00$Body$PanControl$Pan1';        
$namefield2='ctl00$Body$PanControl$Pan2';
$namefield3='ctl00$Body$PanControl$Pan3';
$namefield4='ctl00$Body$PanControl$Pan4';

$valfield1='6280';       
$valfield2='2370';
$valfield3='3101';
$valfield4='3135';

$cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';

$regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
$regexEventVal  = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';

function regexExtract($text, $regex, $nthValue)
{
$regs = Array();
if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) {
$result = $regs[$nthValue];
}
else {
$result = "";
}
return $result;
}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$data=curl_exec($ch);

$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,1);
$eventval = regexExtract($data, $regexEventVal,1);

$postData = '__VIEWSTATE='.$viewstate
      .'&'.$namefield1.'='.$valfield1
      .'&'.$namefield2.'='.$valfield2
      .'&'.$namefield3.'='.$valfield3
      .'&'.$namefield4.'='.$valfield4
      ;

curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

after run the code this is error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be > displayed.

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: The error is coming from the website, not necessarily your code. Do you have access to the logs on the server that you are connecting to?

Comment: no website doesn't  have any error, you can check the form with 6280 2370 3101 3135 , i dont have access on the server too.

Comment: 500 is a server error from the website, so I don't understand how you can say it doesn't have any error.